# how to test my facebook chatbot?

Tags: chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am developing a chatbot for facebook messenger platform using wit.ai.

It hard to find bags, I would like to test at least basic flows(conversations) of my bot.
Does anyone know frameworks or tools for testing my chatbot?

Comment: So you want a program to test the conversations?

Comment: I suggest you give https://www.hubtype.com/products/chatbots.html a try as it manages the whole chatbot lifecycle: creating, testing, publishing and analyzing (Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders)